# yacc/bison grammar: whats the difference between two rules?

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc, parser-generator

I have to write some sort of parser and it's quite easy with tools like yacc and bison. But I have the following question:

```
NotRec: /*empty*/
| NotRec T_NOT
| NotRec T_MINUS
;

Expr:
| Term /*1*/
| NotRec Term /*2*/
;
```

What is the difference between rule 1 and 2?

In my opinion `NotRec` can be empty (because it has an empty branch) and therefore `Term` should be the same as `NotRec Term`. But if I remove the first rule I get different results!

Comment: What different results? With the first rule, the grammar is ambiguous and bison should warn you that there is a shift/reduce conflict.

Comment: no, I get no bison error. But the parser (bison-result) accepts different inputs...

Comment: I get a shift/reduce warning from bison. Maybe there is something you're not mentioning. Please provide a more complete example; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You haven't shown the rules for `Term`, so it's a bit speculative, but your rule 1 allows for a single-item expression that is a `Term`, and nothing else, while rule 2 allows for a `Term` preceded by a `NotRec`, which is appears to be a possibly empty sequence of `T_NOT` and `T_MINUS` items. Also, as @rici mentions, there are some ambiguities (the most obvious one is that an empty string could represent either a `NotRec` or an `Expr`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the grammar is ambiguous, as `NotRec` will match 0 or more `T_NOT` or `T_MINUS` tokens, so if you have an `Expr` which has no such tokens before the `Term`, it can be matched by either rule 1 or rule 2.

If you remove the `NotRec: /*empty*/` rule, then `NotRec` becomes useless as it won't match any finite sequence of tokens.  This changes the language, removing any finite strings of `T_NOT`/`T_MINUS`.

If you remove the `Expr: Term` rule, that gets rid of the ambiguity without changing the langauge.

If you use this grammar as-is with yacc or bison, you'll get a shift/reduce conflict due to the ambiguity.  The default conflict resolution of using the shift will resolve the ambiguity without changing the language -- as long as there are no other conflicting uses of those tokens in the part of the grammar you left out.  It will use rule 1 for any `Expr` with no `T_NOT`/`T_MINUS` instructions and rule 2 for any `Expr` with one or more such tokens.  This is equivalent to changing the `NotRec` rules to

```
NotRec: T_NOT
      | T_MINUS
      | NotRec T_NOT
      | NotRec T_MINUS
      ;
```

This makes `NotRec` match one or more tokens instead of zero or more.